# Use multiple LightNodes

Tags: sprite-kit, sklightnode

I found out that I can't use more than 8 LightNodes, I can add them as a child but they are not shown on the view.

Comment: Sorry, it's not immediately clear to me what and where the problem is from this image. Can you add some hieroglyphics to point out where and what the problem is?

Comment: To whoever came up with the idea of not letting new users add images... you thought wrong.

Comment: I changed the image.

Comment: So you have two shadows overlapping in the middle of this image?

Comment: Thats ok. I mean the light grey area, the LightNode doesn't outshine the shadow of the other LightNode.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you're talking about. Can you point exactly at what the problem is?

Comment: Yeah sry I don't speak english very well :/.

Comment: But I try my best, both LightNodes cast a light and my problem is that the LightNodes don't cast their light in the shadow of the another LightNode. I marked these areas I hope you know now what I mean.

Comment: I think you're seeing the right thing. Two shadows, overlapping, multiply their "darkness". The light is equally influencing the left and right.

Comment: The overlapping zone is right. But the area where only one shadow is, isn't effected by light of the other LightNode, and that includes the region where both LightNodes are, which I marked and that makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: What is making the shadows?

Comment: The mountain in the middle of the image.

Comment: I think it was @knight0fdragon who famously said SpriteKit isn't really a game engine, and clarified how it's only a very basic framework for making games. That's probably the most sage thing anyone has ever said about Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong? I add two light with Lighting Mask equals to 1 and a node (the rectangle) with Shadow Cast Mask equals to 1.

In both cases (lights can see each other, or rectangle is in between) you have areas with no shadow, a medium shadow from one of the light and a strong shadow from both light. In these both cases, the falloff is 0.

If you add some falloff the you can clearly see the effect of each light.

[Both in shadow cone of each other[image: in shadow]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPeMj.png)

[Both in light cone of each other[image: in light]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8SE1.png)

[Both in shadow cone of each other with some fall off[image: with fall off]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqZzn.png)

Comment: Yeah I have the same effect. But I don't understand why there are medium shadows, because when there is a light there can't be shadow.  For instance, if you put 20 lights around the rectangle, we should have a very dark shadow around the object, despite the fact that we have 20 lights around it. Maybe I'm completely wrong, but in my opinion it does not make any sense.

Comment: At this point, I think you're asking why does SpriteKit work the way it works.  The fact that "in real life" there might not be a shadow is not related to what SpriteKit does with lighting.  If you play with the ambient light color and light color values, you will probably find the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Maybe I will, but I don't think so. I want to make a strategy game and I thought LightNodes are a good and easy way to implement the fog of war, but sadly they aren't.

Comment: @Chris light decay in spritekit is not really realistic as cumulative lighting effects. Realistic effects are very computing intensive (realistic energy model is complex).

Comment: argh, fog of war... this is, oddly enough, best done with "clouds" that are part transparent bitmaps (.png files are perfect) and can be added where you need, layered as you need, and animated as you need. Large cloud sprites, basically... http://i.imgur.com/jpQMMt1.jpg @Chris